# FTP file upload using php

Tags: php, ftp

I need to upload a file automatically from a local computer to a remote server.  I have found the following code on here:

```
<?php
require_once('ftp.php');

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
    exit;
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

`ftp.php` is my file with the ftp authentication information.  The connection works but I am getting the following error:

```
There was a problem while uploading C:/xampp/htdocs/testbcos/accounting/checkslastmonth.csv
```

EDIT:  I amnot sure if this makes a difference or not, but here are my $remote_file and my $file:

```
$file = "C:/xampp/htdocs/testbcos/accounting/checkslastmonth.csv";//tobe uploaded
$remote_file = "/home/bookcell/public_html/testbcos/accounting/checkslastmonth3.csv";
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Also, is it possible to do this if the file is on a mapped drive on my local server?
Thanks.

Comment: Check the remote directory have right permission to upload the file?

Comment: The remote directory has permissions of 777 for testing purposes, and I refreshed the directory and tried again with the same error, so I don't think that is the issue

Comment: remain things all goes in a right way. Most probably the user dont have the right privileges to access the remote server..

Comment: Make sure you enable warnings in PHP. `ftp_put` will definitely issue a warning with more details on the error.

Comment: try to set passive mode with `ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);`

Comment: where should that go?  Right before i upload the file?

Comment: @Jim put it after `ftp_login`

Comment: Sadly, it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

First thing: Try to set passive mode. You need it if you're sitting behind a firewall. (What probably is the case)

```
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); // after ftp_login
```

Second, you have to change to dir first:

```
ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/home/bookcell/public_html/testbcos/accounting/');
ftp_put($conn_id, 'checkslastmonth3.csv', $file, FTP_ASCII);
```

If you want to know what's really going on, try to get error message with [error_get_last()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) or
[$php_errormsg](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php)

Comment: I looked at the servers error logs and I am getting this:  [STDERR] PHP Warning:  ftp_put(C:/xampp/htdocs/testbcos/accounting/checkslastmonth.csv) [<a href='function.ftp-put'>function.ftp-put</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /chroot/home/bookcell/bookcellaronline.com/html/testbcos/accounting/ftpUpload.php on line 19  I think I am destined not to get this to work

Comment: try to get the local file with `$file = realpath(__DIR__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'checkslastmonth.csv';` Else the error it pretty clear: does the local file really exists at that location?

Comment: @Jim so it looks like you're running the script on a server and want to "upload" a file from you're local machine? Could it be that you need an html upload script and not a ftp upload?

Comment: Here is the result:  /checkslastmonth.csv

Comment: Meaning I need to use a form? I am going to be uploading the same file, just updated, every time I use a particular program.  That is why I went with the ftp script.

Comment: try `realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'checkslastmonth.csv'`

Comment: but think about: the server does not have access to your local machine's file system. So you need to run this script on the local machine or use client side code (html/javascript) to upload a file.

Comment: /chroot/home/bookcell/bookcellaronline.com/html/testbcos/accounting/checkslastmonth.csv